# Unable to get local storage variable in Wicked Pdf

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I have stored some data "xyz" in java script local storage. Now I'm trying to access that in wicked pdf but unable to do so. It's working when i display as html but does not print that in the pdf.

That's what i have saved:

```
localStorage.setItem("my_id", "xyz");
```

In file.pdf.erb:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout((function () {
    //console.log(localStorage.getItem("dashboard_bar_chart_actual_situation_control"));
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "HELLo "+localStorage.getItem("my_id");
    window.status = "FLAG_FOR_PDF";
}), 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the localStorage value on the same page that you are rendering to PDF, or are you setting it on a prior page, and then expecting it to be retrieved on the PDF page?

The latter won't work in the default PDF rendering mode, because your HTML is saved to a file on-disk, and opened in a virtual browser, without any context (localStorage, cookies) of what happened on other pages (unless you supply them as options to `wkhtmltopdf`, at least for cookies).

You could explicitly set it during render, so that it becomes available, something like this:

```
<script>
  // Render it to the page, so it is executed when the JS runs:
  localStorage.setItem("my_id", "<%= "xyz" %>")

  // Use it:
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "HELLo "+localStorage.getItem("my_id");
</script>
```

Alternatively, you can use the WickedPDF middleware, which attempts an in-place replacement of the HTML you see with a PDF version, without saving it to a temporary HTML file on-disk, but that also may not work well, depending on how the JS code gets executed.